# T-SQL CASE / Subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a T-SQL query below that returns results based on date

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN date ='2012-10-31' then Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [Amount],
    SUM(CASE WHEN date ='2012-10-31' then Discount1  ELSE 0 END) AS [Discount 1],
    SUM(CASE WHEN date ='2012-10-31' then Discount2  ELSE 0 END) AS [Discount 2]
    SUM(CASE WHEN date ='2012-10-31' then Amount - Discount1 - Discount2 ELSE 0 END) AS   
[Total Amount]
FROM
    Orders
```

Current results:

```
Amount   Discount1   Discount2   Total
--------------------------------------  
100.00   5.00        5.00        90.00
```

I would like to have this run and display/group by month. Any ideas?

```
                         Amount    Discount1  Discount2   Total
                       -------------------------------------------
  October                100.00     5.00        5.00       90.00
  November               100.00    10.00        5.00       85.00
  December               200.00    20.00       10.00      170.00
```

Comment: group by month... how are you aggregating? sum, average?

Answer (score 5):

If you need it grouped by month, you can try something similar to this:

```
select datename(mm, date) month,
  sum(amount) amount,
  sum(discount1) discount1,
  sum(discount2) discount2,
  sum(amount - discount1 - discount2) Total
from orders
group by datename(mm, date)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/160f0/1)